# Aggregate Queries with too many groupings

Tags: aggregateresult

I'm curious about the efficiency of an aggregate query with too many groupings. I'm working on a scheduled Apex job that will run daily, and compare two aggregated fields with some fields from a parent object to update the parent object based on a few conditions.

Let's say I'm monitoring how much revenue each of my company's users are bringing in, so I can decide who to assign new accounts to. I want to keep track of how much each account currently is bringing in, but for new accounts I'm more interested in how much they're expected to bring in. For accounts that are expected to end business with us soon, I'm not going to completely ignore their incoming revenue, but I'm going to weigh it less heavily, as a function of how much time they have left to work with us. (For what it's worth, my real use-case is involving custom objects, so I'm not sure if I actually used Opportunities correctly here, apologies if this example doesn't make sense from a business perspective)

I could write the following SOQL query to make my calculations:

```
[
 SELECT 
   sum(Amount) GRANDTOTAL, sum(ExpectedRevenue) EXPECTEDTOTAL, AccountId ACCOUNT,
   Account.OwnerId SALESPERSON, Account.CreatedDate ACCOUNTCREATEDDATE, Account.EndDate__c ACCOUNTENDDATE
 FROM Opportunity
 GROUP BY
   AccountId, Account.OwnerId, Account.CreatedDate, Account.EndDate__c
]
```

Or, I could write the following two SOQL queries, and use them both to make my calculations:

```
[
 SELECT 
   sum(Amount) GRANDTOTAL, sum(ExpectedRevenue) EXPECTEDTOTAL, AccountId ACCOUNT
 FROM Opportunity
 GROUP BY AccountId
]
[
 SELECT
   Id, OwnerId, CreatedDate, EndDate__c
 FROM Account
]
```

My gut says that grouping a whole bunch of fields (and who knows, maybe 4 is not "a whole bunch", but there could be a scenario where a similar situation comes up with 10 fields in that second query) is probably slower than breaking this up into two queries, and cross-referencing each other. I am certain that it would be easier to work with fewer fields to extract from an AggregateResult. But I wonder if it's any slower or less efficient in any way to run the two queries.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be really subjective on various aspects (indexed fields, data volume) etc. But, generally I can say, you may want to use **MAX** aggregate function instead by grouping by on fields, which will never have separate groups.

Also, both the queries are grouping on account, so cost (execution time) must be almost close.

For e.g. as you are creating a group on account id, field like account owner, created date need not be grouped, as they'll always have only one value. So if you change your code to (not verified):

```
SELECT 
   sum(Amount) GRANDTOTAL, 
   sum(ExpectedRevenue) EXPECTEDTOTAL, 
   AccountId ACCOUNT,
   MAX(Account.OwnerId) SALESPERSON, 
   MAX(Account.CreatedDate) ACCOUNTCREATEDDATE,
   MAX(Account.EndDate__c) ACCOUNTENDDATE
FROM Opportunity
GROUP BY
AccountId
```

Also, general best practice, you can also use Query Plan feature in Developer console to gauge the actual cost of a query execution and ascertain optimal queries. Read more here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334796&type=1&mode=1